# Add a Enterprise Wiki as a subsite in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wiki, templates

I created an empty SharePoint 2010 site collection in which I added many subsites like an Agile Dashboard and a Blog. I wanted to add a Enterprise Wiki but it does not show up in the list of site template. Apparently, SharePoint only allow to add Enterprise Wiki when creating a site collection from the "Publishing" category. It seems strange because for me it makes total sense to have a Wiki along with any kind of site.

Do anybody has an idea how to enable this template in an empty site collection ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem myself.

I realised that using the SharePoint 2010 Designer allowed me to add an Enterprise Wiki. But it was giving me an error telling me that the Publishing Infrastructure feature was not enabled on the site collection. So I just activated it from site settings and the template magically appeared in the the New Site wizard :)